# Landscape app turns portrait in multitasking - swift

Tags: ios, swift, landscape, multitasking

when I enter multitasking in iOS (by double-clicking the home button), my swift game that is landscape only turns portrait which totally warps the view. I've run out of ideas how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like it's not really landscape only in that case... Check your settings.

Comment: it is... in device orientation only landscape left and landscape right are checked and also, app doesn't change orientation when I am using it....only when I access the multitasking

Comment: I'm also having this issue. My solution – which I am not pleased with – is to add a static portrait image rotated 90% (it looks landscape when on screen) on applicationWillResignActive and remove it when my application resumes again.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable portrait mode in the settings of your app where you also can set your Storyboard etc. Just check if only `Landscape left` and `Landscape right` is checked.

Comment: It is disabled, when I use the app, it works perfectly. Only when I access the multitasking the game warps like it were in a portrait mode